# What's the WPF equivalent to Flex's width height 100%?

Tags: c#, wpf

What's the WPF equivalent to Flex's width height 100%?

Comment: In `WPF` it is sinful to define fixed `Height` or `Width` until really required. What do you wish to do?

Comment: I don't want to fix height and width, I want the containers to take full space when window is resized. i am using stackpanel with vertical orientation but things come next to each other, I have a stackPanel inside this StackPanel i want this stackpanel to take all the space between a top container and a bottom container

Comment: yea 100% isn't fixed it resizes acc to the available space, somethings are good in flex like 100% and you don't need to write OnPropertyChanged(PropertyName) in the setter while implementing MVVM, in flex just write [Bindable] , calling a method is lame here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, using Grid is the best bet here.

Answer (score 0):

There are some types of containers (e.g. DockPanel) which force their content to fill the container.

You can also bind element's Width and Height to parent's Width and Height,

Answer (score 0):

StackPanel does not contain this behaviour - use a DockPanel instead - last child will fill out the panel.